# Start a subprocess, wait for it to complete and then retrieve data in Python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm struggling to get some python script to start a subprocess, wait until it completes and then retrieve the required data. I'm quite new to Python.

The command I wish to run as a subprocess is

```
    ./bin.testing/Eva -t --suite="temp0"
```

Running that command by hand in the Linux terminal produces:

```
    in terminal mode
    Evaluation error = 16.7934
```

I want to run the command as a python sub-process, and receive the output back. However, everything I try seems to skip the second line (ultimately, it's the second line that I want.) At the moment, I have this:

```
    def job(self,fen_file):
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        from sys import exit

        try:
            eva=Popen('{0}/Eva -t --suite"{0}"'.format(self.exedir,fen_file),shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)            
            stdout,stderr=eva.communicate()
        except:
            print ('Error running test suite '+fen_file)
            exit("Stopping")

        print(stdout) 
        .
        .
        .
        return 0
```

All this seems to produce is

```
    in terminal mode

    0
```

with the important line missing. The print statement is just so I can see what I am getting back from the sub-process -- the intention is that it will be replaced with code that processes the number from the second line and returns the output (here I'm just returning 0 just so I can get this particular bit to work first. The caller of this function prints the result, which is why there is a zero at the end of the output.) exedir is just the directory of the executable for the sub-process, and fen-file is just an ascii file that the sub-process needs. I have tried removing the 'in terminal mode' from the source code of the sub-process and re compiling it, but that doesn't work -- it still doesn't return the important second line.

Thanks in advance; I expect what I am doing wrong is really very simple.

Edit: I ought to add that the subprocess Eva can take a second or two to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Since the 2nd line is an *error message*, it's probably stored in your `stderr` variable!

To know for sure you can print your `stderr` in your code, or you can run the program on the command line and see if the output is split into `stdout` and `stderr`.  One easy way is to do `./bin.testing/Eva -t --suite="temp0" > /dev/null`.  Any messages you get are `stderr` since `stdout` is redirected to `/dev/null`.

Also, typically with `Popen` the `shell=True` option is discouraged unless really needed.  Instead pass a list:

```
[os.path.join(self.exedir, 'Eva'), '-t', '--suite=' + fen_file], shell=False, ...
```

This can avoid problems down the line if one of your arguments would normally be interpreted by the shell.  (Note, I removed the `""`'s, because the shell would normally eat those for you!)

Comment: Hi, Perhaps the 'Evaluation error' is misleading, but it is not an error message: it is the desired output of the subprocess which is calculating the squared difference between a calculated quantity and a measured one. However, passing a list, removing the shell=true and removing the double quotes as you suggested has got it working. Thanks!

Comment: @ppyvabw You know, it might have been the `"--suite"{0}"` -- I didn't mention you were missing the `=`, but included it in my version!

Answer (score 0):

Try using subprocess check_output.

```
output_lines = subprocess.check_output(['./bin.testing/Eva', '-t', '--suite="temp0"'])
for line in output_lines.splitlines():
    print(line)
```